# Stuck in 3rd circle of hell deleting AppEngine application

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to delete some AppEngine applications from my Google account.

To delete the apps, I need to cancel billing, but I am not the billing administrator. Unfortunately the billing administrator has deleted his entire account, so neither can he.

Anyone suggest away out of this 3rd circle of hell ?

Thanks.

Comment: contact app engine support?

Comment: You used to be able to take over the billing if you were an Owner.. but now they added the billing administrators section.. can you verify that there is noone on that list that actually has an account?